# Capitalize each first letter of the words in a string

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

How can i capitalized each first letter of the result of this

```
self.namE.text = currentUser.displayName

self.handle.text = snapshotValue?["handle"] as? String
```

instead of "Bruce willis" i would like to have "Bruce Willis", i created this extension to capitalized the first letter

```
extension String {
    func capitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
        return prefix(1).uppercased() + dropFirst()
   }
}
```

but it obviously capitalize only the first word in a string, so how i have to modify this extension to get the right result? ( i looked in the doc but i didn't understand very well )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` in swift4 has already a `capitalized` computed property on itself, so without implementing anything yourself, you can get the desired result using this:

```
self.namE.text = currentUser.displayName.capitalized
```

E.g.:

```
self.namE.text = "bruce willis".capitalized
```

Comment: ah so easy, thank you